# Bootstrap Div Height Expand with Select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal with a dropdown inside it. When i expand the dropdown, it creates a scrollbar.

My goal is to have the div auto expand to the height of the select menu when it is triggered.

Is this possible to do so i don't have to have all that wasted space in the modal?

[image: Modal Image]

Comment: why dont you try to increase size of modal on onChange() Event for select option..?

Comment: I need to be able to do it when the dropdown is clicked. I think onchange only happens when a new value is selected which would be too late.

Comment: this may help u.. http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/4BUqB/ trick to avoid scrollbar..

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try. I use a plugin called Chosen for my dropdowns but i assume it will act the same way. I will provide feedback shortly!

Comment: sure..best luck for it..